# How to Clean Base64 File of Carriage Returns and Line feeds?

Tags: text, base64, png, decode

I have a base64 file that needs to be cleaned of carriage returns and line feeds before it can get decoded into an image file. How do you clean it properly?

Here's a portion of the text:

[image]

I tried removing all instances of `\n`, and `\r`, but when I decoded it, it seems that PNG file type is detected but the image is not displayed just some portions of the text file. I also tried cleaning with `\n, \r, \N`, and `\R` but it didn't work. I'm wondering if I'm missing out on something.

Here's what I get when I decode it:
[image]

Comment: "/n" or "\n"? It's the backslash ("\") that is the escape sequence. Where are you getting the file from? The original spec for Base64 demands that every 76 characters should be put on a new line. Are that what these line breaks are from, or was it something else? How are you actually trying to remove the line breaks?

Comment: Sorry. Should have been \n instead of /n. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The file is an output of a software I am testing. I was told to remove the header, then clean it from carriage returns and line feeds. Afterwards, decode it and I should be able to see the same image file I created with the software

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the new lines, you can use the following command in your Terminal:

```
tr -d '\n' < base64.txt > base64_new.txt
```

This will create a new file without the line breaks.

Comment: Hi, I’ve updated the post with a photo to show how the file appears on my screen. You mean I’ll replace “base64.txt” with the filename of my base64 file to be converted, then the next file name is the new “cleaned” file?

Comment: Finally got it. Thanks! Initially I was thinking the brackets means it is a placeholder. Turns out it was part of the command.

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove "\r\n" from your base64 file.

```
tr -d "\r\n" < ~/base64.txt > ~/base64_no_endlines.txt
```

Comment: Hi, I’ve updated the post with a photo to show how the file appears on my screen. I can’t find an exact instance of “\r\n” being together on the file.

Comment: The carriage return is '\n' on Linux or '\r\n' on Windows. They are invisible characters unless you set your text editor displaying them. Your text editor is telling that there are 13 lines and header is "dataimage/pngbase64"

Comment: Interesting info you got there. I guess that explains why I am seeing the file in a different way. Thanks!